# Error in installing Pdfminer package in Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, spyder, pdfminer

I have installed `Anaconda 2.5` and used spyder with `Python2.7` for sometime. I used `pdfminer` those days. Then I wanted to use `Python3.6`. So I have uninstalled Anaconda and installed `Anaconda3.5`. And there is no problem in using `Python3.5` and I used more packages too. But now am trying to install `pdfminer`. Am getting some errors.

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/4f/e1df0437858188d2d36466a7bb89aa024d252bd0b7e3ba90cbc567c6c0b8/pdfminer-20140328.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                     

    File "C:\Users\PRIYA~1.MUT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzctx8lo\pdfminer\setup.py",line 3, in <module> 
       from pdfminer import __version__
File "C:\Users\PRIYA~1.MUT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzctx8lo\pdfminer\pdfminer\__init__.py", line 5                 
       print __version__                                                                                                                       
       ^                                                                                          

`SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(__version__)?`
```

I knew there is some issues because `print __version__` needs to be like `print (__version__)`. but I don't know where I need to edit. And this path

> "C:\Users\PRIYA~1.MUT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzctx8lo\pdfminer\pdfminer__init__.py"

doesn't exist on my system.Kindly help me in solving this.

Comment: Try to look for this file `pdfminer-20140328.tar.gz` in your system and remove it. That could help.

Comment: There is no file named `pdfminer-20140328.tar.gz` in my system. But I've solved this problem with your idea.

Comment: Ok, good to know!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually downloaded `pdfminer-20140328.tar.gz` from the link  https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/  and tried to install it using the command `pip install -e <path>`. But I got the same error. Then I have opened the `pdfminer__init__.py` file and edited accordingly to `Python3.6`. I have no idea why `pdfminer` package doesn't support `Python3.6` directly. Eventhough installed, there is some dependency error. So I can't use that in `Python3.6`.

Comment: From https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/index.html: Python. (for version 2.4 or newer). A code that works with Python 2.4 certainly doesn't work with Python 3. It's simply too old; last release was in 2010.

Comment: OMG. So is there any alternative package for pdfminer in Python3.6 . I need to extract texts from pdf's.

Comment: I don't know but let me [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+extract+texts+from+pdf). I see [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/); textract supports PDFs via [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) and [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six); the latter is a fork of pdfminer update for Python 2+3. I'm sure there're much [more](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pdf).